# SQL overload - weird query

Tags: taxonomy, mysql

My hoster claims the following SQL query is overloading the server and causing it to perform slowly and threatens to disable my account. I can't seem to find a bottleneck - can anyone help me detect where it all comes from?

Executed 1 min ago for 8 sec on Database --> mydb_name.

```
SELECT * FROM tsk_posts 
    LEFT JOIN tsk_term_relationships ON
        (tsk_posts.ID = tsk_term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT JOIN tsk_term_taxonomy ON 
        (tsk_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tsk_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
    WHERE 
        tsk_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND 
        tsk_posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND 
        tsk_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' 
    AND 
        ( tsk_term_taxonomy.term_id = 4 OR tsk_term_taxonomy.term_id = 103 OR
          tsk_term_taxonomy.term_id = 19 OR tsk_term_taxonomy.term_id = 20 OR 
          tsk_term_taxonomy.term_id = 5 OR tsk_term_taxonomy.term_id = 2 OR 
          tsk_term_taxonomy.term_id = 14 )
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: not an SQL guru but I bet the probable cause is the "ORDER BY RAND()". Using "SELECT tsk_posts.ID" may be helpful.

Comment: Agred.. get rid of ORDER BY RAND().  See http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: What WP plugin is creating a query like that?

Answer (score 2):

"order by rand" can be quite an expensive query. A random number must be generated and then be used to access into the result set.

How many rows are in each of the tables?
Are there any indexes?
Run an explain plan to get a better idea as to where the cost is.